# Is it true any real matrix add an identity matrix is full rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I think the statement is true, since it is how regularization works in linear model (where adding $\lambda I$ to $X^TX$ make it full rank). But why?

Comment: Not *any* real matrix. Obviously it's not true of $-\mathbf{I}$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog thanks. how about other cases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$X^TX$ is a symmetric matrix.
It is diagonalizable with real eigenvalues.

Let those eigenvalues equal $\lambda_1, \cdots \lambda_n$

If we choose any of the $\lambda_i$ above.

$(X^TX - \lambda_i I)$ will create a singular matrix.

However, $(X^TX - \lambda I)$ where $\lambda \ne  \lambda_1, \cdots \lambda_n$

then the eigenvalues of $(X^TX - \lambda I)$ equal $\lambda_1 - \lambda,\cdots,\lambda_n-\lambda$ none of which are equal to $0.$ Hence, $(X^TX - \lambda I)$ is non-singular.

Nearly any perturbation to a singular matrix will make for a non-singular matrix.

Comment: thanks!!, I have many years of mis-understanding, and your answer helped me a lot

Comment: could you explain more on the last statement? I know why $(X^TX - \lambda I)$ is full rank, but why $(X^TX + \lambda I)$ is also full rank?

Answer (score 1):

For any square matrix $A$ such that $A$ is not invertible, and for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $A+\tfrac{1}{n}I$ is in fact invertible. This technique is used to show that invertible matrices are dense in the set square of matrices.

Of course,  it is not true for all matrices, as shown by the example $-I$ and $I$.

Many theorems about the general linear group related to this are really interesting. In particular, it is possible to show that $\mathrm{GL}(n)$ has two connected components! You should see Rudin's book on analysis for this.

This is also of interest for numerical analysis since every singular matrix can be approximated by a "close to singular" matrix.

I hope you find this interesting.

Comment: If A=diag(0, -1/n) which is singular, and A + I/n = diag(1/n, 0) is still singular. So here $n$ has to be large enough to make sure their eigenvalues don't cancel.

Comment: The matrix $A$ does not depend on the integer $n$.

Comment: because you said for any singular A, so I can construct for example A = diag(0, -1). Then you said for all natural number n, then I can choose n = 1, but A + I = diag(1, 0) is singular.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. My statement holds for all $n$ except maybe finitely many.